# How can i remove a paragraph tag from a string?

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a string:

```
$string = '<p>[Some_string value="2" width="3" someMoreInfoHere]</p>'
```

I need help writing a regular expression on finding and replacing both `<p>` and `</p>` with `''`.

I know that I can use a string replace as here:

```
$string = str_replace("<p></p>", "", $string);
```

However, I only want the paragraph begin, and end to be replaced, when the occurance of either a paragraph begin tag, followed imidiatly by a squared bracket like so:

```
'<p>['
```

and in the case of a close bracket, followed imidieatly by a closing paragraoh tag, like so:

```
']</p>'
```

I hope this makes sense, I am a little confused myself :/

Comment: So if there is `<p>[` and/or `]</p>`, should it be removed ?

Comment: not removed but replaced by ']' and '['

Comment: and when it's `<p>` `</p>` should it be replaced by `[` `]` ? It's a bit unclear what you *exactly* one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$string = str_replace(array('<p>[', ']</p>'), array('[', ']'), $string);
```

Hope it's what you're looking for.

No need for a regular expression.

Comment: Yes it was.. i almost got the same result :) Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the confusion guys and especially @Hamza:

I figurred it out myself, daaahhhhhhh

This is what i was looking for:

```
$string = str_replace("<p>[", "[", $string);
$string = str_replace("]</p>", "]", $string);
```

Comment: You could merge them and use `$string = str_replace(['<p>[', ']</p>'], ['[', ']'], $string);` or `$string = str_replace(array('<p>[', ']</p>'), array('[', ']'), $string);` if the brackets notation for array is confusing :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you know about [strip_tags()](http://www.php.net/strip_tags)?

```
$string = '<p>[Some_string value="2" width="3" someMoreInfoHere]</p>';
echo strip_tags($string);
```

Comment: This will remove *all* tags

Comment: You can use the optional second parameter to specify tags which should not be stripped.

Comment: Except you aren't using that here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, didn't know about this function, it will be usefull for later development :)

Comment: @WahyuKristianto yeah, seems legit. We could maybe just exclude ~50 tags

Comment: Is `str_replace()` can replace ~50 tags more simple than `strip_tags`?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto `strip_tags()` will remove *all* tags, even those without `[]`. So it's use here is just wrong